# I am trying to run the sample project after compiling the pjsip library but it doesnt allow me to

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pjsip

When I run the sample project that came with pjsip in "pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/ios/ipjsua.xcodeproj" I get the following error message

> The file “ipjsua” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.

I have followed the tutorial on [this website](https://blog.csdn.net/wszawsz33/article/details/47105123) and everything compiled successfully.

What I tried:

1. To clean the project.
2. I have check that the values in info.plist are correct
3. I did change the build Identifier in the general tab

Is there something else that I missed that I need to add or change?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- Deleting DerivedData content: `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`; close Xcode; install pods again if you have any; open Xcode and build
- Create new project in Xcode with the same name of your project that doesn't run, and copy the Info.plist from the new project and replace it in your old not running project

Comment: Will deleting the DerivedData affect my other xcode projects?

Comment: @Coder_98 Yes, but it shouldn't be a problem: derived data is generated during each app build process and it contains intermediate build results, generated indexes all this in order to help speed up build time. You can think of it as a cache. It is therefore safe to delete it.

Comment: It did not seem to fix the problem. It is still saying that I do not have permission.

Answer (score 0):

i had similar issue. In project build settings i did change valid architerctures from armv7 to arm64 and it managed to run on device. also i did configure pjsip compile arch to arm64(export ARCH="-arch arm64") before configure-iphone command. Hope it helps